# Move files from multiple directories to single directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the `os.walk()` module to go through a number of directories and move the contents of each directory into a single "folder" (dir).

In this particular example I have hundreds of .txt files that need to be moved. I tried using `shutil.move()` and `os.rename()`, but it did not work.

```
import os 
import shutil 

current_wkd = os.getcwd()
print(current_wkd)

# make sure that these directories exist

dir_src = current_wkd

dir_dst = '.../Merged/out'

for root, dir, files in os.walk(top=current_wkd):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):  #match files that match this extension
            print(file)
            #need to move files (1.txt, 2.txt, etc) to 'dir_dst'
            #tried: shutil.move(file, dir_dst) = error
```

If there is a way to move all the contents of the directories, I would be interested in how to do that as well.

Your help is much appreciated! Thanks.

*Here is the file directory and contents*

```
current_wk == ".../Merged
```

In `current_wk`there is:

```
 Dir1 
 Dir2 
 Dir3..
 combine.py # python script file to be executed
```

In each directory there are hundreds of `.txt`files.

Answer (score 0):

Simple path math is required to find source files and destination files precisely.

```
import os
import shutil

src_dir = os.getcwd()
dst_dir = src_dir + " COMBINED"

for root, _, files in os.walk(current_cwd):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".txt"):
            full_src_path = os.path.join(src_dir, root, f)
            full_dst_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, f)
            os.rename(full_src_path, full_dst_path)
```

Comment: That won't work. It will only move the current directory contents == the combine.py. (It will give a traceback error - can't find .txt file). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare the complete path of source file, and make sure dir_dst exists.

```
for root, dir, files in os.walk(top=current_wkd):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):  #match files that match this extension
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), dir_dst)
```